# dropdownpicker is hiding behind the Flat List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I have two dropdown picker, these two are dependent on each other and I'm facing two issues:
first: my dropdown is hiding behind the flat list.
second: if I click on one drop down second drop down should show the result but it shows result when I click on first dropdown twice.
Here is the snack link: https://snack.expo.dev/@anamika1593/carlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved first issue by using   ListHeaderComponentStyle={{ zIndex: 100000 }}
still figuring out the second one

Answer (score 1):

I am facing similar issues last week if you are also using the ***react-native-dropdown-picker*** library.

There are two options(Both are the props of **< DropDownPicker />**):

1. `dropDownDirection`
2. `zIndex`

set `dropDownDirection` will force the open menu direction to the top but it should not be the best choice.

```
dropDownDirection="top"
```

setting `zIndex` to a bigger value will force the dropdown to appear on the top of the component and should be solve the issues.

```
containerStyle={{zIndex: 99}}
```

Answer (score 0):

user this property  zIndex={1000}

<DropDownPicker
zIndex={1000}
...
/>